# What are "services provided by Ubuntu"?

Tags: discussion, scope

The [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for Ask Ubuntu says:

> We welcome questions about:
>
> - Services provided by Ubuntu

What does "services provided by Ubuntu" mean?

Is that meant to be "services provided by  Canonical Ltd." instead?
If not, aren't questions about *Ubuntu One* (and other Canonical services) on other OSs off topic here in AU?

Comment: You are right, that should be clarified.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu One is a good example. It isn't so much Ubuntu, but is something that is in part supported here (by Canonical), even its Windows client.

Comment: Maybe we should clarify to eliminate the ambiguity, since Ubuntu doesn't *provide services* but Canonical does.